# This bash command is not running correctly inside Makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

Inside Makefile I have like this:

```
release:
    version=$$(poetry version | cut -f2 -d " ")
    echo "release $$version"
```

If I run,the statements from my terminal they run without any problem.

```sh
> version=$(poetry version | cut -f2 -d " ")
> echo "release $version"
release 0.0.2
```

But if I run,

```sh
> make release                                                                                                                                  
version=$(poetry version | cut -f2 -d " ")
echo release $version
release
```

You see in the output, beside `release` the version no. is not shown.

Comment: Why is this tagged `bash`? Do you have `SHELL := /bin/bash` in the makefile? Otherwise, it defaults to using `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Each command in a `make` recipe runs, by default, in its own shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each command in a makefile recipe is executed in its own shell process. So the variable assignment takes place on one shell process, which then exits and its variables are discarded. The `echo` command executes in a new process that doesn't have that variable.

You need to escape the newline and use a `;` command delimiter to run the commands in the same process.

```
release:
    version=$$(poetry version | cut -f2 -d " "); \
    echo "release $$version"
```

Comment: Using `&&` instead of `;` would fail if `poetry` or `cut` failed.