# Defining local variable in Makefile target

Tags: gnu-make, makefile

How to define local variable in Makefile target?

I would like to avoid repeating filename like:

```
zsh:
    FILENAME := "text.txt"
    @echo "Copying ${FILENAME}...";
    scp "${FILENAME}" "user@host:/home/user/${FILENAME}"
```

But I am getting an error:

```
FILENAME := "text.txt"
/bin/sh: FILENAME: command not found
```

Same with `$(FILENAME)`

Trying

```
zsh:
    export FILENAME="text.txt"
    @echo "Copying ${FILENAME} to $(EC2)";
```

Gives me an empty value:

```
Copying ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This bash command is not running correctly inside Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67080096/this-bash-command-is-not-running-correctly-inside-makefile)

Comment: @G.M. well, no. The question is `How to declare a local variable in Makefile`. Defining it through the shell is just a workaround.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't define a make variable inside a recipe.  Recipes are run *in the shell* and must use *shell syntax*.

If you want to define a make variable, define it outside of a recipe, like this:

```
FILENAME := text.txt
zsh:
        @echo "Copying ${FILENAME}...";
        scp "${FILENAME}" "user@host:/home/user/${FILENAME}"
```

Note, it's virtually never correct to add quotes around a value when assigning it to a make variable.  Make doesn't care about quotes (in variable values or expansion) and doesn't treat them specially in any way.

Answer (score 3):

The rules for a target are executed by the shell, so you can set a variable using shell syntax:

```
zsh:
    @FILENAME="text.txt"; \
    echo "Copying $${FILENAME}..."; \
    scp "$${FILENAME}" "user@host:/home/user/$${FILENAME}"
```

Notice that:

- I'm escaping end-of-line using `\` so that everything executes in
  the same shell
- I'm escaping the `$` in shell variables by writing `$$` (otherwise
  `make` will attempt to interpret them as `make` variables).

For this rule, which apparently depends on a file named `text.txt`,
you could alternatively declare `text.txt` as an explicit dependency and then write:

```
zsh: text.txt
    @echo "Copying $<..."; \
    scp "$<" "user@host:/home/user/$<"
```

Comment: Do I need `\\` in the second case?

Comment: Escaping the lines in such a way would not allow me to suppress `echo "Copying $${FILENAME}...";` string from makefile output, right?

Comment: The `@` at the beginning of the rule suppresses `make` from echoing the rule before executing it. That's why both examples here start with `@`, because that appears to be what you wanted from your question.

Comment: And it would also suppress the `scp "$<" "user@host:/home/user/$<"` which I would like to keep for "user". Moreover, declaring a file as a dependency breaks thins because this file is located in subdirectly and I am getting the file copied to `/home/user/subdir/text.txt`

Comment: Re: questions about suppression, just try it and see what happens. If you can't declare the explicit dependency, just use the first example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eval](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) to set variables in a recipe. From [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74742720/9208887), I understand that you can even create pseudo local variables that way, by automatically prefixing them with the target. This is achieved by prefixing the variable with `$@_`.

```
mytarget:
    $(eval $@_foo = bar)
    @echo mytarget: $($@_foo)

other: mytarget
    @echo other: $($@_foo)
```

Now we can see that this works as intended. `mytarget` has the variable, while `other` cant see it.

```bash
$ make other
mytarget: bar
other:
```